# HTML5 Localstorage help needed

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm fresh to JS and i was wondering how i could implement this scenario to my code.
Im creating a simple tapping game for android using html, css and js. Whenever my object gets clicked on, 10 points gets added to score. I need this score to saved locally. So when the game restarts the score is there loaded.

Here are the game code:

```js
var score = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").hide();
  $("#bug").autoBounceOff(true);
  $("#bug").moveTo(140);
  $("#bug").speed(0.8);

  //When bug is clicked on
  $("#bug").click(function() {
    score = score + 10;
    $('#score').html('Points: ' + score + '') + 10;
  });
})

function showMenu() {
  $("#menu").show();
  $("#bug").css("visibility", "hidden");
  $("#bug").css("animation-play-state", "paused");
  return;
}

function resume() {
  $("#menu").hide();
  $("#bug").css("visibility", "visible");
  $("#bug").css("animation-play-state", "running");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div id="score">Points:</div>
  <div id="menuheader" onclick="showMenu()">M</div>
</div>
<div id="menu">
  <div id="start" onclick="resume()">resume</div>
</div>
<div id="bug"></div>
<div class="bottomwall"></div>
<div class="topwall"></div>
<div class="leftwall"></div>
<div class="rightwall"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyfoz8h0/2/)

Comment: There is not HTML in fiddle... DO post your code in OP as well...

Comment: — Check console for error.. Include `jQuery` library as well...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly. As for what you're asking, the [MDN page on `localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) should give you enough information.

Comment: I have added the code snippet to the question, however notice that there are errors in the console which need to be fixed.

Comment: It’s unclear where your exact problem is at implementing the saving mechanism with `localStorage`. There’s no attempt at that in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basic localStorage usage.

When you starting your script, you can test if localStorage.score is already set with:

```
var score = 0;
if(!localStorage.score){
    localStorage.score = 0;
}
score = parseInt(localStorage.score);
```

then in your click event:

```
localStorage.score = score + 10
```

Comment: @DenizAltay You are welcome, If it works, please mark it as help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please check this link can help you :
**http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp**
you can make an empty array and use:
 **`array_name.push()`**  for your values.
then you can  use **`localStorage.setItem("score" , array_name)`** 
and you can retrieve this value again using: 
 **`localStorage.getItem("score");`** 
                                                              that return array values and you should check first: 
                                        if it has values or not to avoid undefined or exceptions in your application.
if you need a demo for this just tell me now and i will upload it.